# Group is not a dimension 'Field__c'

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics, saql

Hello I have the following problem, in Analytics I try to group my data set for a specific field and it does not allow it, I get an error

Group is not a dimension 'Field__c'

What is this error?

regards

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem.

In Einstein Analytics there are two types of Category, quantitative data and qualitative data.

Those that are countable as number type for example are quantitative data.

Those of type Text or Dates are of qualitative type, qualify to be dimension and therefore are fields by which the data can be grouped.

The field Field__c was a numeric field therefore it did not qualify as Dimension and it could not be used for grouping, change the data type in Salesforce so that it was of Text type and now this is a Dimension and I can group the data through this field.